# Django forms dynamic generation and validation

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

Let's say I have the following model

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(default='untitled')
    # Bar is a MPTT class, so I'm building a tree here
    # Should not matter for my question...
    root = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
    leaf = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
```

To create new Foo objects I want to make use of a ModelForm like this:

```
class FooForm(ModelForm):
    # possibly custom validation functions needed here...
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
```

My view looks like this:

```
def create(request, leaf_id=None):
    form = FooForm(data=request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        new = form.save()
        return redirect('show.html', root_id=new.root.id)

    return render('create_foo.html', 
                  { 'form': form })
```

As you can see, the view function should be used to handle two different use-cases:

1. `/foo/create/`
2. `/foo/create/4`where `4` is a leaf-ID.

If the leaf-ID is given, the form obviously isn't required to show a form field for this. Furthermore, `root` can be determined from `leaf`, so it isn't required aswell.

I know that I can dynamically change the used widgets, so I can switch them to `HiddenInput`, but I would like to not even show them as hidden to the user. But if I dynamically exclude them, they are not available for form validation and the whole process will fail during the validation process.

What I would like to achieve is: Show only form fields to the user, that are not yet pre-filled. Is there any best-practice available for this case?

Comment: If the url is `/foo/create/`, you will display a new form. What should be displayed in case the url is `/foo/create/4`?

Comment: @RahulGupta A form aswell, but without fields for `leaf` and `root`, at least not visible...

Comment: Value of `leaf` will be 4. How do we get the value of `root`

Comment: @RahulGupta I simplified my example. As I described, `leaf` and `root` are MPTT-model instances. And all `leaf` objects do know their `root` node. But I don't think this matters to my question, does it?

Comment: No, it does not matter that much. Check if the solution helps your use case.

Comment: It would be better if you have 2 separate Class-Based views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do that by overriding the `__init__()` method of `FooForm`.**

We override the `__init__()` method and check if `instance` argument was passed to the form. If `instance` was passed, we disable the `root` and `leaf` form fields so that it is not displayed in the template.

We will pass `instance` argument to the form when the request is of type `foo/create/4` i.e. `leaf_id` is not `None`.

**forms.py**

```
class FooForm(ModelForm):    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # call the 'super()' init method
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None) # get the `instance` form attribute 
        if instance and instance.id: # check if form has 'instance' attribute set and 'instance' has an id
            self.fields['root'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled' # disable the 'root' form field
            self.fields['leaf'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled' # disable the 'leaf' form field

    # custom validation functions here
    ....

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
```

In our view, we first check if `leaf_id` argument was passed to this view. If `leaf_id` was passed,we retrieve the `Foo` object having leaf id as the `leaf_id`. This `instance` is then passed when initializing a form and is updated when `form.save()` is called. We will use the `instance` to populate the form with values as the attributes set on the `instance`.

If `leaf_id` is not passed, then we initialize `FooForm` with `data` argument.

**views.py**

```
def create(request, leaf_id=None):
    # Get the instance if any
    instance = None
     if leaf_id:
        instance = Foo.objects.get(leaf_id=leaf_id) # get the 'Foo' instance from leaf_id

    # POST request handling
    if request.method=='POST':    
        if instance:      
            form = FooForm(data=request.POST, instance=instance) # Populate the form with initial data and supply the 'instance' to be used in 'form.save()'
        else:
            form = FooForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new = form.save()
            return redirect('show.html', root_id=new.root.id)

        return render('create_foo.html', 
                  { 'form': form })

    # GET request handling    
    if instance:
        form = FooForm(initial=instance._data, instance=instance) # form will be populated with instance data
    else:
        form = FooForm() # blank form is initialized        
    return render('create_foo.html', 
                  { 'form': form })
```

Comment: Whow, this is nearly exactly the solution I came up with myself in the last hour! I think yours is even a bit better, because while your view-function doesn't fit exactly my use case, it can be adjusted to not only create but also modify existing `Foo` objects. Thank you!

Comment: I wrote thinking you might need to modify `Foo` objects. ;) This code can be cleaned further if 2 separate CBVs (`FormView`) were used which will remove the `leaf_id` and the `is_valid` condition from the view.

Comment: Slightly modified the ans to handle the `GET` and `POST` requests with comments for better clarity.